# Hiding column and row headings in SpreadsheetGear control

Tags: .net, spreadsheetgear

Is there a way to hide the A,B,C column headers and 1,2,3 row headers in the SpreadsheetGear 2010 control?  We are using this as a display only control and showing these headings gives the impression that the data can be edited.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.  It is in the WorkbookView.ActiveWorksheetWindowInfo.DisplayHeadings.  You can show and hide several elements from this class, including gridlines, formulas and outlines.

Cool.

Answer (score 0):

I found it under WindowInfo.
For example:

```
IWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];
ws.WindowInfo.DisplayHeadings = false;
```