# Restrict User from changing the column width or row height in spreadsheetgear

Tags: vb.net, excel, winforms, spreadsheetgear

Is there any way to restrict the users from changing width of column or height of row of the worksheet on my windows form?

Answer (score 0):

A work around for the time being has found. I am hiding the headings of my active sheet as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426555/hiding-column-and-row-headings-in-spreadsheetgear-control). But please any better idea because this is not a solution you know.

Answer (score 0):

SpreadsheetGear 2023 / V9 introduced the ability to apply fine-grained worksheet protection options to a worksheet (i.e., all of the checkbox options in Excel's "Protect Sheet...." dialog).  You could use this feature to apply a light touch of worksheet protection--where you restrict row / column formatting but allow everything else.  Example:

```
// Create a new workbook and some local variables to the worksheet and cells.
IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveWorksheet;
IRange cells = worksheet.Cells;

worksheet.Protect(
    // Specify null if you don't want to protect the sheet with a password.
    password: "MyPassword1234", 

    // Enables worksheet protection
    protectContents: true,

    // Restrict formatting of rows / columns (e.g., resizing).
    allowFormattingColumns: false,
    allowFormattingRows: false,

    // Allow other options, or also restrict as desired.
    protectDrawingObjects: false,
    protectScenarios: false,
    allowFormattingCells: true,
    allowInsertingColumns: true,
    allowInsertingRows: true,
    allowInsertingHyperlinks: true,
    allowDeletingColumns: true,
    allowDeletingRows: true,
    allowSorting: true,
    allowFiltering: true,
    allowUsingPivotTables: true,

    // True enforces protection only on the user interface (i.e., WorkbookView) and
    // allows your code to make API calls to modify the protected worksheet.  False 
    // will not even let your own code make modifications.
    userInterfaceOnly: true
);
```

Please see the [SpreadsheetGear API Samples > Worksheet > Protection sample](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Samples/API/WorksheetProtection) for more examples of using this new API. See also the following documentation links:

- IWorksheet.[Protection](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet%7EProtection.html) property and [IProtection](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.IProtection_members.html) interface.
- IProtection.[AllowFormattingRows](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.IProtection%7EAllowFormattingRows.html) / [AllowFormattingColumns](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.IProtection%7EAllowFormattingColumns.html)
- IWorksheet.[Protect](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet%7EProtect.html)(...) method